# How to maintain application compatibility between Android versions?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-version

Some Android codes (Java) work on specific versions and others throw exceptions/errors.

This is very common, so much so that achieving a stable version of an application usually requires a lot of testing and in several different versions.

What would be the tip to solve this problem? I heard that developing testing on a device with the latest version would guarantee compatibility compatibility for the olders, is this true?

Are there any `tags` where we can organize questions regarding version compatibility?

Comment: You may want to use [the AndroidX libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) as much as possible instead of using the corresponding Android platform APIs directly. As far as testing on different devices is concerned, you could look into using Firebase Test Lab or other similar services.

Comment: As I know Firebase Test Lab not work well, but I'll check.